# Write a callback function to print three characters sequentially using a provided async function with random timeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I was asked the following question in a JavaScript interview. I was unable to answer it. Please help!

```
const printString = (string, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(string);
        callback();
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
};
```

Call function printString three times with characters 'a', 'b' and 'c' and write a callback function such that a, b and c are printed in sequential order. Use the callback function however you want.

Any assistance is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you able to share what your attempt looked like? Maybe you were close to solving it and missing something simple?

Comment: `setTimeout` inside the `printString` is it part of the question ?

Comment: @brk Yes it is part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the call to `printString` in a promise and pass `res` as a callback. When `callback` is executed inside the `setTimeout`, the promise gets resolved and it will move to the next item in the loop.

```js
const printString = (string, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(string);
    callback();
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
};

const inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

(async () => {
  for (const n of inputs) {
    await new Promise(res => printString(n, res));
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use Promises, the simplest answer is to chain the `printString` method itself as a callback.

```js
const printString = (string, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(string);
        callback();
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
};

printString('a', 
      () => printString('b', 
          () => printString('c', () => undefined)));
```

Since its an interview question, the `Math.random()` is probably to deflect your mind into thinking that they will be called out of order, but they will be not.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not completely clear to me since nothing is mentioned if we can use promise. I presume we can use it , so my solution will be to create a promise and then in the resolve we can call the callback

```js
function printVal(val) {
  console.log(val)
}

const printString = async(string, callback) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(callback(string));
  }, Math.random() * 1000))

};


const caseFunc = async() => {
  const items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  for (item of items) {
    const val = await printString(item, printVal);
  }
}
caseFunc()
```

Comment: I don't think modifying the given function is allowed.